# Character Counter & Limiter - code clarity

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote small character counter & limiter.
You can test it here: [Char Counter & Limiter](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/8YdCh/)

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.counter').each(function(index) {

    $('.counter p span').html('0'); // set character length to 0
    $('input', this).keyup(function() {

        var CounterDiv = $(this).parent(); //
        var Limit = $('p', CounterDiv).html().split(' / ')[1];
        var CurrentLength = $(this).val().length;

        if (CurrentLength == Limit) {

            $('p span', CounterDiv).html(CurrentLength);
            return false;

        } else if (CurrentLength > Limit) {

            var str = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
            return false;

        } else {

            $('p span', CounterDiv).html(CurrentLength);

        }
    });

});

 });
```

**Have you got any suggestion how can I improve that? I'm not 100% sure with the syntax.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use native html `maxlength` attribute for inputs

here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8YdCh/16/

**html**

```
<input name="input1" type="text" maxlength="8" />
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.counter').each(function(index) {
        $('.counter p span').html('0'); // set character length to 0
        $('input', this).keyup(function() {
            var $countSpan = $(this).parent().find('.var-count'); // find the count span
            var countValue = $(this).val().length + " / "  + $(this).attr('maxlength'); // format value for count span 'current value lenght / maxlength attribute'
            $countSpan.text(countValue); // set formatted value to your column span
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you spear a minute and explain this please ? `$(this).parent().find('.var-count').text($(this).val().length + " / "  + $(this).attr('maxlength'));`

Comment: it's just to indicate your symbols in your span.. give me a second, I'll add comments

Comment: In this case you don't have any logic for limiting the value in textbox. It's done by the browser itself.